# Fatal error: Class 'Products\Summary\Html\Section' not found

Tags: php

```
Fatal error: Class 'Products\Summary\Html\Section' not found
```

I get the above error on the following code.  I've verified that Summary\Html\Section() is indeed the namespace of the class I'm trying to access.  I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working... any thoughts?

```
<?php

namespace Products;

use Products\Base as ProductBase;
use Products\Mapping as MappingInterface;
use Summary\Html;

class Product1 extends ProductBase implements MappingInterface {
    /**
     * Complete PDF mapping
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function render() {
        $preTable = new Summary\Html\Section();
        $row = $preTable->addRow();

        $row->addColumn()->setValue('Headline one')->addClass('first'); 
        $row->addColumn()->setValue('Headline two')->addClass('first');

        return $preTable;
    }
```

My section class:

```
namespace Summary\Html;

use Summary\Html\Element;


use Summary\Html\Section\Row;

class Section extends Element {
```

Comment: The class is being explicitly included or loaded with an __autoload function, right?  Sorry for the obvious question but this kind of stuff is easy to miss, especially if it's a malfunctioning __autoload.  I'd suggest putting an echo('something') at the top of your class file just to make sure it's being included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it thinks Summary\Html is part of the Products namespace. Try this:

`$preTable = new \Summary\Html\Section();`

Comment: Oh, and just to point out: when you declare `use Summary\Html;`, that is the same as `use Summary\Html as Html;` so this should also work: `$preTable = new Html\Section();` See here for more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php